# Google cache isn't updating after redoing my website

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, google-cache

I have a website I completely redid almost a month ago. However, Google is still caching the copy before then.

I've tried submitting a request to remove it from Google Search Console several times, but get rejected every time.

How do I force Google to cache the new website?

Comment: Do mean [cache](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en) or index? If it's the former, then how does this question differ from your previous one [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122037/google-has-old-cached-copy)?

Comment: @dan I mean the cached copy Google serves

Comment: Google's cache will update over time, and is often slow and problematic. It doesn't affect SEO in anyway however. You can inform Google that the snippet or cache is outdated using the [Remove Outdated Content tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1) as indicated in the first link above. The second link contains some feedback as to being problematic and a workaround at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Do not request a removal if all you did was change the URLs content. Submit them for indexing via the URL inspection tool, then wait.

If your pages have gone and now 404, then you can request a removal. All that will do is remove them from search faster. They will be removed automatically on next crawl anyhow.

If they redirect, just wait until Google picks it up.

Comment: They have the links. They are serving a month old page in their cache and are showing old links. I resubmitted my site map, but the cached copy is WAY different from my site because I redid it

Comment: Google is still having issues from their indexing issue a few weeks back. Data like this and from GSC may be out of date